# Are the Q affected by widespread changes in the timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-eu

I suspect the answer is "No", but felt I should ask anyway. Given that the everything we know about the Star Trek "universe" has changed with the Abrams reboot, I was wondering how this would affect the rest of the galaxy, especially the nearly omnipotent species like the Q or Organians. To keep the question specific, though, let's limit it to the Q Continuum.

**Have we seen anything on-screen or in EU materials that would indicate the Q are subject (or immune, even) to widespread changes in the timeline?**

I know that we've seen Q himself interact with alternate timelines on a couple of occasions, but those were localized events involving the Enterprise-D or Voyager crews. When it comes to large-scale alterations like the Mirror Universe, I don't think we've seen the Q involved...

Comment: @Richard, I'm not sure the two are duplicates. I'm referring more to changes within the same timeline, not multiverses. I suspect that, like Guinan, a Q would know everything changed.

Comment: My answer to the dupe addresses the fact that Q seem immune to timeline changes as well.

Comment: @Richard - hmmm, you may have a point. Then again, both "All Good Things" and "Tapestry" were localized timelines that only seemed to affect Picard's memory of events. If a reality-altering event went back far enough to alter even a Q's personal timeline, would the Q know about it?

Comment: The implication is that the Q have visited the start and end of the universe. There's very little you could do to affect their place in the timeline that they haven't already done to themselves.